# What's the phenomenon where it looks like more particles exist at relativistic speeds?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

From the perspective of an observer moving close to the speed of light, the surrounding environment has very high energy which leads to pair production.  What is the name of this phenomenon?  I can't remember it, and Google searching is revealing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking of the Unruh Effect. It says that observers undergoing high *acceleration* see an increased vacuum temperature.

Mandatory Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect

Remember that according to special and general relativity, observers traveling at a constant velocity (speed and direction) all have to observe the same things in their own reference frame.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  That's what I was looking for!